# Is there a way to either remove or prevent these lines from appearing on my texture when using UV maps?

Tags: texturing, uv

[image: example]

Is there a way to create textures using a UV map without these black lines appearing along each polygon, I want to use different colors, on the different polygons without the colors leaking over the edge, but I don't want these lines on the parts that use the same color, I know I can do it by hand in a photo editor but again I use different colors and the process would be super tedious and time-consuming, is there a better way to do this texturing, otherwise is there a way to hide polygons in the texture paint menu so I can only texture the polygons I want to texture.

Comment: Those lines don't appear by default. Do you see them in a render? If not, it's just a wireframe visibility enabled in object settings. If yes, either these black lines are in a texture (then resign from it), or you have some bevel or wireframe modifier or something like that.